# Running more than one function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, console

I am having trouble understanding why my application will terminate after running only one function. I have coded the application as follows...

```
const readline = require('readline');

const io = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

console.log(
  'Welcome. This application will check if a given year is a leap year.'
);

checkYear();

function checkYear() {
   io.question('Check which year? ', function (year) {
      year % 100 === 0 && year % 400 !== 0
         ? false
         : year % 4 === 0
         ? console.log(year + ' is a leap year.')
         : console.log(year + ' is not a leap year.');
      });

   io.question('Check another year? y/n'), function(response) {
      if (response.toLowerCase === 'y') {
         checkYear();
      } else {
         io.close();
      }
   }
};
```

I have also tried breaking the second prompt into its own function and calling both checkYear and checkAgain back-to-back, but I get the same result. What do I need to do to make the io.question('Check another year') prompt run after the application responds to the first input?

Comment: should be `response.toLowerCase() === 'y'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are expecting another input with 2nd `io.question` call.
In your code, 2nd `io.question` will be executed immediately after the 1st `io.question` without waiting for user to enter anything.

So, you will need to nest the 2nd call inside the 1st call:

```
function checkYear() {
  io.question("Check which year? ", function (year) {
    year % 100 === 0 && year % 400 !== 0
      ? false
      : year % 4 === 0
      ? console.log(year + " is a leap year.")
      : console.log(year + " is not a leap year.");

    io.question("Check another year? y/n", function (response) {
      if (response.toLowerCase() === "y") {
        checkYear();
      } else {
        io.close();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Other than that, couple of typo mistakes are:

- **should be**

```
io.question("Check another year? y/n", function (response) {
...
});
```

**NOT**

```
io.question('Check another year? y/n'), function(response) {
...
}
```

- **should be**
  `response.toLowerCase() === "y"`
  **NOT**
  `response.toLowerCase === 'y'`

You can refer to my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/friendly-lake-b15kkz
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. Still getting used to the syntax, but that fixed me right up! Much appreciated!